# Intel C++ compiler 16.0 broken

Tags: c++, icc

When I try to compile the simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Using Intel C++ Compiler 16.0, it fails with the following errors:

```
Severity    Description                                 Project File                                                                        Line
Error       identifier "__is_assignable" is undefined   TestCPP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits  550 
Error       type name is not allowed                    TestCPP C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits  550
```

Notes:

- I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00
- I am compiling as an x64 win32 console application
- I am using Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 Update 2
- I am running Windows 10.10586.218 (x64)
- I am using an Intel Westmere CPU
- The code example compiles & runs perfectly using Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler

**EDIT**
This is known to Intell according to https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/623368 but I would still actually like a (safe) solution that does not require me to revert to a previous visual studio version.

Comment: @Paul woops meant 2015

Comment: In that case see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/623368)

Comment: Have you tried clean/rebuild options?

Comment: @bkVnet thank you, but I'm worried about using `-D__is_assignable=__is_trivially_assignable`